# Text property of a TextBox does not updated from within a DropDown's SelectedIndexChanged Event

Tags: asp.net-2.0

When I change the text property of any textbox through a dropdown's `SelectedIndexChanged` event, the text doesn't change. Why is this?

Comment: Can you try and be polite?  Also, post your code as it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely need to set `AutoPostBack="true"` on your Dropdown list